# Python: list.sort() query when list contains different element types

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

Greetings Pythonic world. Day 4 of learning Python 3.3 and I've come across a strange property of `list.sort`.

I created a list of five elements: four strings, with a number in the middle. Trying to get `list.sort` to work gave the expected error because of mixing types:

```
>>> list = ['b', 'a', 3, 'd', 'c']
>>> list.sort()
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
>>> list
['b', 'a', 3, 'd', 'c']
```

The list is unchanged.

But then I moved the number to the end, used list.sort again, and got this:

```
>>> list = ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 3]
>>> list.sort()
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
>>> list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 3]
```

OK, an error. But the list has sorted itself, kicking the number to the end. I couldn't find any explanation for this on this site or in Langtangen. Is there some underlying reason for this behaviour? Would it be useful in some situation?

Comment: I assume that python doesn't type check the elements before beginning sorting, successfully swaps a few elements, and then raises an error when it compares two incompatible types.

Comment: Python uses binary sorting for small lists. So that is why it was able to sort the first few before it got to the number. Then you got the error

Comment: No the list has not completely sorted itself, only few items that were able to be compared successfully were moved to their appropriate positions. And as soon python recognized that you're comparing items of different types the operation stopped.

Comment: you wanna avoid using `list` as a variable name, it will mask the builtin `list`

Comment: @RyanHaining - thank you for the advice. It was originally prefixed by other text, which I stripped out. Will look out for that in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the Python 3 [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> This method sorts the list in place, using only < comparisons between
> items. Exceptions are not suppressed - if any comparison operations
> fail, the entire sort operation will fail (and the list will likely be
> left in a partially modified state).

The docs don't guarantee any behavior in particular, but the elements will more than likely be left part-way sorted.  Whatever order they were in when the exception occurred, and this order can vary between implementations, or possibly (but unlikely) two subsequent runs of the program.

If you want to try to sort the items without worrying about an unfortunate re-ordering, you can use the `sorted` builtin function, which will return a new list rather than modify the original.

```
>>> seq = ['b', 'a', 3, 'd', 'c']
>>> try:
...     seq = sorted(seq) # if sorted fails, result won't be assigned
... except Exception: # you may only want TypeError
...     pass
...
>>> seq 
['b', 'a', 3, 'd', 'c'] # list unmodified
```

---

**EDIT:**
to address everyone saying something like

> *once it sees two different types it raises an exception*

I know you are probably aware that this kind of statement is an oversimplification, but I think without being clear, it's going to cause confusion. As an obvious example, you could sort a list with a mix of `int` and `float`.

The following example consists of two classes `A` and `B` which support comparison with each other through their respective `__lt__` methods.  It shows a list mixed of these two types sorted with `list.sort()` and then printed in sorted order with no exceptions raised:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.a = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, B):
            return self.a < other.b
        else:
            return self.a < other.a

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.a)

class B:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.b = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.b < other.a
        else:
            return self.b < other.b

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.b)

seq = [A(10), B(2), A(8), B(16), B(9)]
seq.sort()
print(seq)
```

The output of this is:

```
[2, 8, 9, 10, 16]
```

it's not vital that you understand every detail of this.  It's just to illustrate that a list of mixed types can work with `list.sort()` if all the pieces are there

Comment: "... in a partially modified state" says it all. Probably best to stay away from this in the future. My guess is that it looks at the first element, reads its type, then makes comparisons along the list (sorting as it goes) until it comes to an element with a different type, then stops. Sorry for repeating your answer in my own words - it helps me to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt not necessarily checking the types, if you have two classes you define yourself with `__lt__` methods that can take the other as an argument, there's no reason for it to fail.  This is more apparent when you use a `key`.  The `key` function could handle all of the type dependent decisions as well, consider `seq.sort(key=len)`.  That would work on a list consisting of strings, dicts, sets, and other lists.

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt I've amended my answer to show an example of this, a list with two different types working with `list.sort()`

Comment: Not done classes yet, so I will read up about these. Does that mean that theoretically you could sort lists containing many different class types (sorry if I am using the wrong words)?
Example: using your system above, could I sort a list that contains no sub-lists, just a string of letters, integers AND floating point numbers? I know that '3' is sorted before 'a', and so on, but the number 3 comes at the end. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt yes.  You can pass a `key` function to `list.sort`  each element in the list will be passed to that key function which will return some value that is then compared.  the `key=len` is a common one because `len` is builtin and will sort containers based on their size.  You could `def` your own key function that would give whatever behaviour you want.  I can think of a few ways.  sorting with keys takes some looking into

Comment: this is a bit of a brisk explanation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go#t=10m6s

Comment: This might be a good approach to deal with unstructured (i.e. messy) data sets I get from HPLC software at work. The output is a real mish-mash of text, integers and float numbers and although it doesn't strictly need sorting (before importing into Phoenix software) it would certainly make validating the data input easier. Lots to learn! Thank you.

Comment: @ShaneMHewitt btw I took a look at your profile, based on the languages you have there, watching that video would be a really good demo of how to start writing more Pythonic programs.  Also, if you are getting the lines of your input in a predictable pattern, you could easily sort by a certain element of each line.

Answer (score 8):

I am writing below answer by assuming that I know the data types in the list, might not be efficient. My idea is to partition the given list into sublists based on data type, after that sort each individual list and combine.

```
input= ['b', 'a', 3, 'd', 'c']
strs = list(filter(lambda x : type(x) ==str,input))
ints = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, input))

output = sorted(strs) + sorted(ints)
```

Comment: extend the approach to arbitrary types beyond str and int?

Answer (score 2):

This nothing uncommon. Simply `sort()` do not check whether list contains consistent datatypes, instead it *tries* to sort. So once your element is at the end, it gets analyzed lately, and so algorithm did sorted part of the list *before* it found an error.

And no - it is not useful, as it heavily depends on the implemented sort mechanism.

Comment: Dziękuję lejlot - a partial sort like this helps to visualise what is actually going on behind the scenes. I will stay away from this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

depends on how the data needs to be sorted, but something like this can work

```
l = ['a',3,4,'b']
sorted([str(x) for x in l])
['3', '4', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Generally people don't want to change the data type just to have it in an order

Comment: I suggest `sorted(l, key=str)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same problem recently, and didn't wanted to cast everything to a string, so I did this, hope it helps :)

```
list = ["a", 1, False, None, "b", (1,3), (1, 'a'),(1, [None, False]), True, 3, False]

type_weights = {}
for element in list:
    if type(element) not in type_weights:
        type_weights[type(element)] = len(type_weights)

print(sorted(list, key=lambda element: (type_weights[type(element)], str(element))))
```

It should return something like this:
['a', 'b', 1, 3, False, False, True, None, (1, 'a'), (1, 3), (1, [None, False])]

It should work with any data type (including custom classes)

Comment: Does it sort lexicographically?