# How does sort() work in python ? Is there any preference order?

Tags: python, sorting

my question is how do i sort a list if it contains elements of different type ? and also what is the preference order for sort() ?

```
a = [1,22,7,4]
a.sort()
print(a)
#print(a) gives [1, 4, 7, 22]
b = ['aa','','abc']
b.sort()
print(b)
# print(b) gives ['', 'aa', 'abc']

k = [1,22,'',4]
k.sort()
#TypeError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: list.sort() query when list contains different element types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872314/python-list-sort-query-when-list-contains-different-element-types)

Comment: I've edited my question a bit. Is there any preference order for sort() ?

Comment: Please define "preference order"!

Comment: @KlausD. you get [' ' , 'aa' , 'abc' ] but ['aa','abc', ' ' ] this is also a possibility isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2 you can sort k but python 3 gives an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` which is reasonable. However, if you change the above to:

```
k.sort(key=str)
print(k)
```

You get:

```
['', 1, 22, 4]
```

but you will get some odd results, e.g.:

```
k.append(0.00001)
k.sort(key=str)
print(k)
```

Gives:

```
 ['', 1, 1e-05, 22, 4]
```

So the answer is you convert all of the elements, at comparison time, to a comparable type, i.e. one that has a `<` member, that all of the members can be meaningfully converted to.  The ordering preference is then based on the type and how it does the compare, e.g.:

```
'0.9002' < '1'
True
```

but:

```
'0.9002' < '0000'
True
```