# Python 3: pattern for ordering arbitrary objects (ex, Python 2 style ordering)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, ordering comparisons (`<`, `>`, etc) throw an error if the objects are not orderable:

```
>>> object() > object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'object' and 'object'
```

Is there a standard pattern for using Python 2 style ordering, where some arbitrary total ordering is defined for every object?

Comment: Obligatory "why do you want that?" Useful in determining whether ordering on `hash(obj)` is an option, for example. (Is that an option?) Also, if you had the Python 2 behaviour, would the types like sets that define comparison operators that aren’t total orderings be an issue?

Comment: @r.ook It's implemented; it *returns* `NotImplemented`.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Python 2 implementation sorted things by class name. So an instance of the `AA` class would sort before one of the `BB` class, and they'd both sort before an instance of `CC`. I'm not sure how it did tie breaking between instances of different classes with the same name.

Comment: @chepner Well by that definition I agree - the method object *exists*... but it doesn't do anything in particular which is what I meant by "not implemented".  I probably just phrased it badly.

Comment: (If your objects stay referenced, there’s also `id(obj)`. So, good for non-weak collections. Maybe.)

Comment: I think there is a dupe out, telling you to use something like min( objects, key: whatever) - i.e. making it explicit how to compare instead of using the arbitrary python 2 ordering

Comment: @Ry- two specific use-cases come to mind: ordering arbitrary, heterogeneous, lists (for example, so that diffs can be more meaningful), and ordering tuples where leading elements are meaningful, but trailing elements aren't (as a simple example: `sorted(zip(item_orders, items))`; ofc in this specific case `sorted(…, key=lambda x: x[0])` can be used, but I'm still curious about the general case)

Comment: Something along this line: [python-list-sort-query-when-list-contains-different-element-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872314/python-list-sort-query-when-list-contains-different-element-types)

Comment: @r.ook If, for example, you define `A.__gt__`, then `object() < A()` will call that method when `object.__gt__` returns `NotImplemented`, as `__gt__` is considered the reflection of `__lt__`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes, something like that, but I'm curious about the general case, and whether there is a Python 3 pattern for doing this, or whether it's Just Not A Thing We Do Now.

Comment: @chepner I stand corrected, good point.  Thanks for the education.

Comment: Diffing heterogeneous lists sounds like non-reference-equality, so `id` is out. Not being able to use set difference would be for… an external diff? Ordering tuples… you would always use `key` or the equivalent of it, really. Pretty much anything that made use of this in Python 2 was never a good idea, to be honest, so yeah, IJNATWDN.

Comment: Ah, found the implementation of [Python 2's fallback comparison code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/object.c#L790): If there are no valid comparison operators, the first check if that numeric types sort before non-numerics, then they sort by type name, then by memory address (which is the same as `id` in CPython).

Answer (score 0):

The [`safe_cmp`](https://github.com/wolever/python-safe_cmp) library can be used for safely comparing arbitrary objects in Python 3:

```py
# pip install safe-cmp
>>> from safe_cmp import safe_sorted, safe_order, safe_max
>>> items = [1, None, "foo", {}, object]
>>> list(safe_sorted(items)) # Using "safe_sorted"
[None, {}, 1, 'foo', object]
>>> items.sort(key=safe_order) # Using "safe_order" with key=
>>> items
[None, {}, 1, 'foo', object]
>>> safe_max([1, None, 3, None, 4]) # Using "safe_max"
4
```

(disclosure of biases: I am the author of [`safe_cmp`](https://github.com/wolever/python-safe_cmp))

Comment: Hi David, I found some discrepancies against CPython behavior in your library that you might like to know about. The landing page says that safe_cmp is *a Python 2 compatible implementation of cmp* but there are some counter-examples, e.g. `cmp({1}, {2})` will raise TypeError in Python 2. `safe_order` is also not exactly Python 2 compatible: a list of complex numbers can not be sorted in Python 2.7 either.

Comment: Ahh! Fantastic, thank you very much! I will likely alter the definition of `safe_order` (and friends) so that they are `_mostly_ Python 2 compatible`, since I believe the current behaviour - not throwing an error but returning an undefined result - is inline with the spirit of `safe_cmp`.

Comment: Hey @wim ! I've updated the code + documentation to, I think, make the behaviour more obvious. If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate a second set of eyes to see if there are any other cases I've missed: https://github.com/wolever/python-safe_cmp#values-without-a-defined-ordering